# When i using Spark read parquet from s3, i think partition puruning not work

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I'm trying to read and query a Parquet file on S3 using Spark.

It has approximately 50TB of data, and the data partition by year, month, day

```
#mylog
#|- year=2023
#  |- month=1
#    |- day=1
#    |- day=2
#    |- day=3
#    |- day=4
#    ...
#  |- month=2
#  |- month=3
#  |- month=4
#  ...
#|- year=2024
```

I made a query like the code below

```
parquet_data = spark.read.parquet("s3://test/mylog")
parquet_data.createOrReplaceTempView("mylog")
test = spark.sql(
    "select column1 from mylog where year=2023 and month=10 and day=10"
)
```

but the Read Parqeut part seems to take too long.

I was expecting that the Where condition would trigger partition pruning
and read only the directories needed, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I change the code like below, it works well

```
#change target directory
parquet_data = spark.read.parquet("s3://test/mylog/year=2023/month=1/day=1")
parquet_data.createOrReplaceTempView("mylog")
test = spark.sql(
    "select column1 from mylog where year=2023 and month=10 and day=10"
)
parquet_data.explain(True)
```

why partition puruing not read only neccecery files?
How can i fix it?